# php, mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

// get the recod from the database
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM date WHERE id=?"))
{
        $stmt->bind_param("isssssssss", $id, $mtcn, $amount, $currency, $sender_name, $sender_country, $receiver_name, $comment, $support, $email);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($id, $mtcn, $amount, $currency, $sender_name, $sender_country, $receiver_name, $comment, $support, $email);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // show the form
        renderForm($mtcn, $amount, $currency, $sender_name, $sender_country, $receiver_name, $comment, $support, $email, NULL, $id);

        $stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
        echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
}
```

which generates the following errors / warnings :

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\wamp\www\records.php on line 143

Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute() [mysqli-stmt.execute]: (HY000/2031): No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement in C:\wamp\www\records.php on line 144

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\wamp\www\records.php on line 146

Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch() [mysqli-stmt.fetch]: (HY000/2053): Attempt to read a row while there is no result set associated with the statement in C:\wamp\www\records.php on line 147
```

And the form is not completed with the data from db as i was expecting ... Any advice / help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the use of statements.

In your query statement, you only need to bind one parameter, the id.

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$id = 5; // fetch the fifth record
$stmt->execute();
```

And then you access the values from your query's result by fetching the result object.

Check out the mysqli_stmt::execute exemple, [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Comment: I'm still getting Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\wamp\www\records.php on line 146 . but from my row I see that the number of vars match the number of fields . Am I missing something ?

Comment: Try to replace your "SELECT *" with the exact field list you want to retreive.